# 'startServer.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: shell

I am facing a strange problem. I have a batch file in windows 7 and when i run the file just by double clicking, it runs but with limited access error because it resides inside program files.

When i right click the file and give "**run as administrator**, the batch file throws below error.

```
'startServer.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'wsadmin.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'stopServer.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . . `
```

Below is my batch file , Please check and throw some light on it.

```
@echo off
call startServer.bat server1
call wsadmin.bat -f configldap.py
call stopServer.bat server1
pause`
```

Comment: The administrator account probably has a different PATH environmental variable to your normal user, try making your batch file call /path/to/startServer.bat etc

Comment: Hi Tolanj.. Thanks.. I will try that and post here shortly...

Comment: Hi Tolanj, Thanks .... worked like a charm !!!  Thanks very much for your advise...

Answer (score 0):

*Since this comment appeared to be sufficient as an answer:*

The administrator account probably has a different PATH environmental variable to your normal user, try making your batch file call /path/to/startServer.bat etc